# For Loop to Create DOM element with InnerHTML and Event Handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dojo

I've come across a very strange issue that I have a workaround for, but don't actually know why it's happening.

Essentially, I take an existing DOM element, use innerHTML to create append DOM element, and then put in an event handler for it's onclick event.

```
for(i=0; i<contextMenuModel.length; i++) {
    contextMenuRow = contextMenuModel[i];
    currentRowId = "edit_context_table_row_" + i;

    editTable.innerHTML += "<div id='" + currentRowId + "'></div>";
    row = dojo.byId(currentRowId);

    row.innerHTML += "<span>" + contextMenuRow.labelName + "</span>";
    row.innerHTML += "<span>" + contextMenuRow.eventName + "</span>";

    dojo.connect(row, "onclick", row, rowClickHandler);
}
```

The problem is this: only the last row ends up with the onclick handler. The others do not. It does not matter what browser I'm in, it does not matter if I change dojo.connect to

```
row.onclick = rowClickHandler;
```

Also, if I take out the:

```
row.innerHTML += "<span>" + contextMenuRow.eventName + "</span>";
```

it still does not work.

However, the workaround that I have found (which makes this all the better) is that this works:

```
for(i=0; i<contextMenuModel.length; i++) {
    contextMenuRow = contextMenuModel[i];
    currentRowId = "edit_context_table_row_" + i;

    editTable.innerHTML += "<div id='" + currentRowId + "'></div>";
    row = dojo.byId(currentRowId);

    row.innerHTML += "<span>" + contextMenuRow.labelName + "</span>";
    row.innerHTML += "<span>" + contextMenuRow.eventName + "</span>";
}

for(i=0; i<contextMenuModel.length; i++) {
    row = dojo.byId("edit_context_table_row_" + i);
    dojo.connect(row, "onclick", row, rowClickHandler);
}
```

Such a strange problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find when creating elements dynamically and attaching events to them I usually come out better using `document.createElement`. This ensures your element is getting added to the dom and you have an object to work with instead of concatenating strings.

```
   var divRow = document.createElement("DIV");
   divRow.id = currentRowId;
   divRow.onclick = function(){};
   editTable.appendChild(divRow);
```

Comment: Well throw that check my way then.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the issue. When I do this:

```
editTable.innerHTML += "<div id='" + currentRowId + "'></div>";
```

I am concatenating and then **replacing** the old innerHTML. That means that a new DOM node is generated; this new DOM node is not connected to the old event handler. This leaves the old event handler around, doing nothing. Not to mention that the code is creating and discarding **so** many DOM nodes, this code is really terrible.

Comment: Unless there's a better one. I can't accept it for 2 days. If someone comes up with a better explanation or ways around it, I'll accept that.